# Why is FileInfo.Length of type "long"?

Tags: .net, unsigned, signed

I was just wondering whether anyone knows why the property [`FileInfo.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) is of type `long` instead of `ulong`? I don't think the size of a file can ever be negative.

Was this a general design decision for the .NET framework, since other length properties (e.g. `string.Length`) are also of type long?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ulong` isn't a CLS-compliant type. The framework tends to use CLS-compliant types where possible.

Comment: Why is there (sort of) a "mismatch" between CLS and C#? I mean, both specifications were made by Microsoft, probably at the same time. Or is there really a .NET language which does not support unsigned data types?

Comment: @M4N: I don't know, to be honest... but I wouldn't be surprised to find examples of .NET languages which don't support operator overloading, for example. I think it's reasonable to set a "lowest common denominator" of language features, although I wouldn't like to say whether it was pitched correctly or not.

Comment: I seem to remember that VB.NET had weaker support for unsigned types in the initial version, but I don't know details.

Comment: Half of the languages supported by Microsoft at the .NET introduction didn't support unsigned types (VB and J#).